# Reading a json and writing only certain json objects to csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json where the objects contain some subset of a superset of strings, e.g. the 'ideal' case where all the strings of a superset are included in an object:

```
{
  "firstName": "foo",
  "lastName": "bar",
  "age": 20,
  "email":"email@example.com"
        }
```

However, some objects are like this:

```
{
  "firstName": "name",
  "age": 40,
  "email":"email@example.com"
        }
```

What's the optimal way to only write the objects with each string of the superset to a csv?

If it were simply a case of a string having a null value, I think I'd just use .dropna with pandas and it'd omit that row from the csv.

Should I impute the missing strings so that each object contains the superset, but with null values? If so, how?

Comment: It looks like dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, reading into a pandas dataframe should do the trick. Using the pandas `df.read_json()` will leave a `NaN` for any value not contained in a given json record. So try:

```
a = pd.read_json(json_string, orient='records') 
a.dropna(inplace=True)
a.to_csv(filename,index=False)
```

Comment: The question specifically says that he doesn't want to write records that are missing any of the "superset" of strings

Comment: That did it! Thank you! As a (possibly amusing) aside, I tried another way, which was less elegant: I put the json in a dataframe, wrote the dataframe to csv, put THAT csv into a dataframe, used .dropna, and wrote to a final csv.

Answer (score 0):

Test for all the values you want:

```
x = json.loads(json_string)

if 'firstName' in x and 'lastName' in x and 'age' in x and 'email' in x:
    print 'we got all the values'

else
    print 'one or more values are missing'
```

Or, a prettier way to do it:

```
fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age', 'email']
if all(f in x for f in fields):
    print 'we got all the fields'
```

Comment: you can use set intersection here.

Comment: @mad_ I added a way using `all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have

```
json_string ='[{ "firstName": "foo", "lastName": "bar", "age": 20, "email":"email@example.com"}, {"firstName": "name", "age": 40,"email":"email@example.com"}]'
```

Then you can

```
l = json.loads(json_string)
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Which yields

```
    age email               firstName   lastName
0   20  email@example.com   foo         bar
1   40  email@example.com   name        NaN
```

Then,

```
>>> df.to_dict('records')

[{'age': 20,
  'email': 'email@example.com',
  'firstName': 'foo',
  'lastName': 'bar'},
 {'age': 40,
  'email': 'email@example.com',
  'firstName': 'name',
  'lastName': nan}]
```

or

```
>>> df.to_json()

'{"age":{"0":20,"1":40},"email":{"0":"email@example.com","1":"email@example.com"},"firstName":{"0":"foo","1":"name"},"lastName":{"0":"bar","1":null}}'
```

The good thing about having a `data frame` is that you can parse/manipulate the data however you want before making it a dictionary/json again.